# Create slice of range with large intervals in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I want to get a slice in Go which looks like this:

```
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

In Python I would do this:

```
l = range(100, 600, 100)
```

I know I can do this in Go:

```
l := []int{}
for i:=100; i<600; i+=100{
    l = append(l, i)
}
```

but isn't there anything simpler to create this slice?

Comment: Go's philosophy is kind of minimalistic, and is happy to leave the coding of simple constructs like `range` up to the programmer rather than adding complexity / syntactic sugars to the language itself. It's just their design choice. Milo's answer is a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the same way Python does:

```
func pyrange(start, end, step int) []int {
    // TODO: Error checking to make sure parameters are all valid,
    // else you could get divide by zero in make and other errors.

    rtn := make([]int, 0, (end-start)/step)
    for i := start; i < end; i += step {
        rtn = append(rtn, i)
    }
    return rtn
}
```

With a function.

Obviously only worth the time if you need to do this often. By default Go does not include a function like this, so you need to write your own (or find a third party library) if you want one.